# Convert .pdf string returned from Snappy PDF Generator to .pdf on server to password protect

Tags: php, linux, pdf, symfony-3.4

Our snappy pdf service in our Symfony 3.4 app returns a pdf as a string like so:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âã
1 0 obj
<<
/Title ()
/Creator (??wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5)
/Producer (??Qt 5.11.3)
/CreationDate (D:20211221165455Z)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
```

Since snappy pdf/wkhtmlpdf does not offer password protection, I am trying to write this string to a pdf on the linux server and then password protect it using qpdf and return it as a string to carry on with further processing.

How do I do this in Symfony 3.4 /php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Process component`](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/process.html) to execute any kind of system process you want.

Comment: Thankyou, but the issue is converting the string to a pdf using qpdf. I can’t find any resources online that demonstrate this.

Comment: You could write the string coming from the Snappy pdf service on a temp file and use this as the qpdf input file.